# Swarm Shared Volumes in Azure with Cloudstor

Tags: azure, ubuntu-16.04, containers, docker-swarm

I'm facing some issues with Docker Swarm volumes using Cloudstore Driver (on azure), when we try to update a docker service after the successful creation of it, the update fails with:

`""Error response from daemon: located 1 sets of existing volumes named "esdata" with different collection labels. Please make sure all existing volumes with the same name share the same collection or don't have one at all""".`

In this case, the service that I'm trying to deploy is an Elasticsearch using the official docker image`docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.1`
Using Docker UCP version 2.2.9  and Docker: 17.06.2-ee-6, build e75fdb with a compose file.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
elasticsearch:
image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.1
networks:
  - test
environment:
  - cluster.name=elasticsearch-infra-cluster
  - bootstrap.memory_lock=false
  - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
ulimits:
  memlock:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
volumes:
  - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
ports:
  - 9200:9200
volumes:
esdata:
  driver: cloudstor:azure
networks:
  test:
```

I have tried to delete all containers, config files and volumes manually,and recreate but did't help.

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-and-volume-persistence/24703) to add a persist volume with a docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Yes, but this method don't create a replicated volume between all the docker swarm workers.

Comment: If you want to share files between containers?